# Add Visual C++ property sheets using CMake

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, propertysheet

I'm currently porting a gcc project to Visual C++. It's defined in a CMake file, and I have created a Visual C++ property sheet to aid in compatibility (GccCompat.props). Everytime the Visual C++ project files are regenerated by CMake, the property sheet has to be added manually, since I don't know how to add it automatically. So, the question is:

How can I tell CMake to add a property sheet to the generated Visual C++ solution?

Comment: This is one of my few beefs with CMake: it often seems to limit you to the lowest common denominator between tools, or else is esoteric in its support of special features. I'm no expert, but my guess is that you'll have to do some sort of postprocessing on your generated files.

Comment: Any idea on how to do post-processing on the generated files? I would have my own script post-process them but it seems that CMake will re-generate as a part of the VS build process, overwriting my changes. There also doesn't seem to be a post-generate hook on CMake...

Answer (score 11):

This functionality has made it into the nightly build of CMake (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/e390991846825799e619e072a28f1da58b7c89ba), although not into a stable release yet. Theoretically, it will be in the next release, and CMake releases are made relatively frequently.

To use, you would set the `VS_USER_PROPS` property on a target. Eg. `set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES VS_USER_PROPS "${props_file}")`.

However, it doesn't appear that you can use multiple property sheets with this option, and, it replaces the default user property file (`$(UserRootDir)\\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props`). To workaround this, property sheets can include other property sheets, so, you could make a 'master' property sheet which includes any other property sheets that you would like to use (including the default user property sheet).

Comment: The property has been renamed to [`VS_USER_PROPS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/VS_USER_PROPS.html)

Comment: Feb 2018 update: This feature is now part of CMake since version 3.8 (if my intel is right). It works fairly well.

Comment: Further update: I've found out my MSVC won't load up the props file unless it's copied next to the `.proj` file and so I had to add a copy command (via `configure_file( ... COPYONLY)`) to make that happen in CMake. Also apparently the _order_ of items in the props file matters.

Comment: So what happens when you try to use this CMake setup for any build system *other* than msbuild?

Comment: in my master props file:
```xml
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
</ImportGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a little bit old but I have recently stumbled upon the same problem while integrating GStreamer into my project. GStreamer comes with a set of extremely well prepared and high quality Property Sheets and I wanted to use them instead of hacking things around in CMake.

Fortunately, this issue is only limited to Windows and Visual Studio. So here's my solution:

The idea is to use **Visual Studio's .user file** feature. CMake does not generate this file so it's pretty safe to generate it at configure-time. At configure time you may generate a file that has the ***EXACT*** name as your project file but ends with a .user extension.

### Partial Solution:

If your project file is named `my_project.vcxproj`, you need to create another file next to it called `my_project.vcxproj.user`. [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862524.aspx):

> A user file (.vcxproj.user) stores user-specific properties, for
>   example, debugging and deployment settings. The vcxproj.user file
>   applies to all projects for a particular user.

The contents of this file for importing property sheets is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="/path/to/sheet1.props" />
  <Import Project="/path/to/sheet2.props" />
</Project>
```

Not flawless, but works until CMake starts supporting property sheets. The file can be created by using CMake's [`file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) command at configure-time.

### Potential Caveat:

I have noticed when I add property sheets this way, sometimes they do not show in the Property Manager window (might be a bug in Visual Studio Community 2013) but they always are imported properly and dependencies are resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which properties you need. A few could be set directly in CMake, like in this example for multiple configurations:

```
set (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "A;B;C;D" CACHE STRING "Configurations" FORCE)

foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )

    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${OUTPUTCONFIG}                "/ZI /Od")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_${OUTPUTCONFIG}         "/debug")

endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

Apart from variables [listed here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables), I think CMake has no possibility to attach property sheets.

Comment: @kfsone Your point 1 is rather irrelevant as this is a 5 year old answer. And linking to "non-official" pages is not forbidden.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't suggest it was some form of moral violation, but a significant portion of the answer is firewalled behind a link that *no-longer* points to the official site, erasing the value of the answer, and something which *is* discouraged -- answers are encouraged to quote the relevant bit of the linked page to protect against exactly this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Specifically - the *only* correct and helpful part of this answer is the link, and it's a deprecated link. If the rest of the answer wasn't inaccurate and unhelpful, then I would have edited the answer to update the link and cite the variables.

Answer (score 0):

in my master props file **main.props**:

```xml
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
</ImportGroup>
```

then, in **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES VS_USER_PROPS "main.props")
```