# set diagnostics:caret from CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I would like to use the new (and better) diagnostic information from visual studio 2017.

To have it enabled to all my project at once I want to declare this flag from my CMakeLists.txt

I tried

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /diagnostics:caret")
```

But when compiling there is an error saying that /diagnostics:classic (which is the default value) is not compatible with /diagnostics:caret

Is there a way to override the default value using cmake ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to know that VS compiler options that CMake does not yet officially support will end up under:

`Properties`/`C/C++`/`Command Line`/`Additional Options`

That's why you get

```
cl : Command line error D8016: '/diagnostics:classic' and '/diagnostics:caret' 
                               command-line options are incompatible
```

But you can give `cl` options globally with the new [`VS_USER_PROPS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_USER_PROPS.html) target property (version >= 3.8).

Here is a working example:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(VSAnyFlag)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.Cpp.user.props" [=[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <ClCompile>
            <DiagnosticsFormat>Caret</DiagnosticsFormat>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
]=])

set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        VS_USER_PROPS "${PROJECT_NAME}.Cpp.user.props"
)
```

**Reference**

- [Add Visual C++ property sheets using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973263/add-visual-c-property-sheets-using-cmake)